# Extracting attributes values dynamically imacros

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

This is the html text

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddltype" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltype" class="page-heading" style="background-color: rgb(255, 244, 244); width: 125px; outline: 1px solid blue;">
            <option value="0">Select Bricks</option>
            <option value="brk_A_price">A</option>
            <option value="brk_B_price">B</option>
            <option value="brk_oth_price">Others</option>

        </select>
.
.
.
.
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlReportOn" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReportOn" class="page-heading" style="background-color:#FFF4F4;width:135px;">
            <option value="0">Select Report For</option>
            <option value="1">Comparison</option>
            <option value="2">Variation</option>

        </select>
```

So from above html I want to extract option Values i.e **brk_A_price,brk_B_price,brk_oth_price** from first select tag and **1, 2** from second select tag.

```
'code to get brk_A_price,brk_B_price,brk_oth_price
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=id:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltype&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS R1 TYPE=option ATTR=value&&TXT

'code to get 1, 2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=id:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReportOn&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS R1 TYPE=option ATTR=value&&TXT
```

However, for every dropdown I would want to change just the **id** attribute, but for the code I tried it is just able to extract the text and not values from `<option..>` tag.

> p.s: [This](http://briks.gov.in/Report/Rept_Building_Brik.aspx) is the site from where I'm extracting data

Any suggestion on what changes should be made.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=id:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltype&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET values1 EVAL("var v = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/value=\"(.+?)\"/g).toString().replace(/value=\"|\"/g, '').split(','); v.shift(); v;")
PROMPT {{values1}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=id:ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlReportOn&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET values2 EVAL("var v = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/value=\"(.+?)\"/g).toString().replace(/value=\"|\"/g, '').split(','); v.shift(); v;")
PROMPT {{values2}}
```

(Perhaps someone may suggest something easier, but the code posted above seems to work anyway.)